# How to find certain text in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know how to find it by ID or something similiar but this is too hard for me.

I want to find if the TR tag has a TD with certain title("Title" in this case) and return Value1 and Value4. I can't change the html because this will be a browser utility for certain website.

Note it has to find several TR's with the same title in the first TD tag and return both values for each.

```
           <tr class="this changes a lot">
                <td title="Title" align="center">
                  <a href="">
                    Link
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                  Date
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                  Value1
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                  Value2
                </td>
                <td>
                  Value3
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                  Value4
                </td>
                <td>
                  Text1
                </td>
                <td>
                  Text2
                </td>
             </tr>
```

Comment: The question is not clear. What do u mean by *return Value1 and Value4*

Comment: Value1 and Value4 will be always in that position (3rd and 6th <td>)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this : get `td` with `title=Title` and traverse to its parent `tr` and get `tr`'s 3rd and 6th child values.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('tr td[title="Title"]').each(function(){
      var value1= $(this).parent().find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
      var value4= $(this).parent().find('td:nth-child(6)').text();
      alert(value1+" "+value4);
   });
 });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8m4Tj/42/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
$(function () {
    $('table tr td').each(function(){
       if($(this).attr('title') == "Title")
       {
           alert($(this).parent('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text())
           alert($(this).parent('tr').find('td:eq(5)').text())
       }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8m4Tj/36/)

Answer (score 0):

If **Value1** and **Value4** `td` will always have the same index position inside the `tr` (3rd ans 6th), you can do this:

```
//--- get the td
var td = $("tr > td[title='Title']");
for(var x = 0; x < td.length; x++){
    //--- search between siblings
    var val1 = $(td[x]).siblings(":eq(1)").text();
    var val4 = $(td[x]).siblings(":eq(4)").text();

    //--- print the values
    alert(val1 + " | " + val4);
}
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZPpm9/1/

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KECVw/)

Use these

Get `<td>` with `title="Title"`

```
$('td[title=Title]')
```

---

Get `<td>` with `Value1`

```
$('td:eq(2)').text()
```

---

Get `<td>` with `Value4`

```
$('td:eq(5)').text()
```